# Does raising a familiar from the dead restore the lost experience points?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

In 3.5 edition, Wizards and Sorcerers suffer an XP penalty if their familiar dies:

> If the familiar dies or is dismissed by the sorcerer, the sorcerer
>   must attempt a DC 15 Fortitude saving throw. Failure means he
>   loses 200 experience points per sorcerer level; success reduces the
>   loss to one-half that amount.

My question is whether you get that XP back again if you raise the familiar from the dead? The Player's Handbook only says this:

> A slain or dismissed familiar cannot be
>   replaced for a year and day. A slain familiar can be raised from the
>   dead just as a character can be, and it does not lose a level or a
>   Constitution point when this happy event occurs.

Okay, so the spellcaster's familiar doesn't lose a level, but what about the spellcaster?

Comment: I just read [Pet Sematary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Sematary) and just the association makes me want to +1 :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under the rules as written, the character still loses the XP, as a penalty for the broken bond.  Obviously your DM can choose to handle this unfortunate situation however she wishes.

To avoid the loss of your familiar you should consider the spell *Familiar Pocket*.

Comment: That's why my wizards have never had familiars... :)

Comment: @BBlake We always had a house rule that unless you were using your familiar for something other than the bonus, it couldn't die.  If you send your familiar in to scout, you take your xp in your hands.

Comment: @C. Ross That's an excellent house rule; I like the idea.  Will implement in future campaigns.  (Our last campaign ended before I could implement my plan to make a miniature cuirass for my falcon, but I had one...)